# Package for retrieving country code from language code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a NPM package that converts language codes like this?

- en-US => USA
- ja => JPN
- pt-BR => BRA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've embedded this in my [Localization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/com.recoyxgroup.localization) package:

```
import { Language } from 'com.recoyxgroup.localization';
let {country} = Language('en-US');
country.getName('en-US'); // English (United States)
country.toString(); // en-US
```

Only specific languages are linked to a Country, so, currently retrieving country from less known languages would result in null. To link a country, the constructor calls at [Language.js#L50](https://github.com/recoyx/Localization/blob/master/src/Language.js#L50) just need a second argument (ISO 3166-1 Alpha-3 country code).

Answer (score 2):

You can look at this extensive package, it covers a lot of different variants

> i18n-iso-countries

https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-iso-countries

```
npm install i18n-iso-countries
```

Comment: It does get country name in a given language, but doesn't provide any language code/name to country code/name conversion.